# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: user.id

Tags: python, django

I don't know why the error is caused even though I designated the author.
I'd appreciate your help.

model & form

```
class SuperTitle(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='debate_author')
    super_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    liker = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='debate_liker')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.super_title


class SuptitForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SuperTitle
        fields = ['super_title']
```

views.py

```
def create(request):
...
  dic = {'super_title' : request.POST.get('sup_title')}
  sup_form = SuptitForm(dic)
  if sup_form.is_valid():
    sup_form.author = request.user
    sup_form.super_title = ...
    sup_form.save()
...
```

[image]

return
**IntegrityError at /polls/debate/create/
NOT NULL constraint failed: polls_supertitle.author_id**

Answer (score 0):

You get this error becouse you want to save form(create new SuperTitle objetd in database) without author.
You need to pass author objectd or id somehow to form. If the request.user is author i recommend form:

```
class SuptitForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SuperTitle
        fields = ['super_title', 'author']
        widgets = {'author': forms.HiddenInput()}
```

and in view:

```
    def create(request):
      if request.method == 'POST':
        sup_form = SuptitForm(request.POST)
        if sup_form.is_valid():
          sup_form.save()
      else:
        sup_form = SuptitForm(initial={'author': request.user}
...
```